# Active Directory server on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, windows-7-x64, adlds

I have a short question: Is it possible to run Active Directory server on Windows 7 Professional x64?
I am testing some software integrated with CAS and I need to cooperate with different directory services like Apache Directory Server and Active Directory.
Do I need the server edition of Windows to make my tests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can download the Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) - formerly known as AD/AM.

See [this blog article](http://www.windows7news.com/2010/02/18/active-directory-lightweight-directory-services-for-windows7/) for details, and [download from Microsoft here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14683).